# Ping other pod in the same & different pod

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, vpc, kubernetes-pod

I would like to ping B pod (node 1) from A pod (node 0) but it's unreachable. However, pinging pod in the same node can not be reachable too.
I am setting up new cluster for trying Kubernetes from [Kelsey](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-the-hard-way/blob/master/docs/11-pod-network-routes.md).

I have tried to use this link as my reference [Kubernetes: Can't ping pods across nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51589849/kubernetes-cant-ping-pods-across-nodes)

```
Node - IP Private - IP Pod
worker-0 - 10.240.0.20 - 10.200.0.0/24
worker-1 - 10.240.0.21 - 10.200.1.0/24
worker-2 - 10.240.0.22 - 10.200.2.0/24
```

> route -n

**worker-0**

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.240.0.1      0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 ens4
10.200.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 cnio0
10.240.0.1      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    100    0        0 ens4
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
```

**worker-1**

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.240.0.1      0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 ens4
10.200.1.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 cnio0
10.240.0.1      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    100    0        0 ens4
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
```

**worker-2**

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.240.0.1      0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 ens4
10.200.2.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 cnio0
10.240.0.1      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    100    0        0 ens4
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
```

I have done setting up VPC Netowrk Routes like this [link](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-the-hard-way/blob/master/docs/11-pod-network-routes.md).

After that i followed this reference [Kubernetes: Can't ping pods across nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51589849/kubernetes-cant-ping-pods-across-nodes)

`route add -net 10.200.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 10.240.0.21` in worker-0

The result is

```
SIOCADDRT: Network is unreachable
```

I tried it in worker-0, worker-1, worker-2 and got same result.
Eventhough worker-0 can ping to worker-1 (10.240.0.21), reachable.

My expectation when i am in Pod A (worker-0) with IP Pod 10.200.0.3, i can ping to Pod B (worker-1) with IP Pod 10.200.1.3. And also, i can ping to Pod C (worker-0) same with Pod A.

Does this step should be using Calico or Flannel ? or Should we can ping other pod from different node without Calico or Flannel (only CNI setting) ?

> Additional Information

I am using Docker not runc & containderd.
So, i installed Docker manually from this [link](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/).

In kubelet.service, `--container-runtime=remote` become `--container-runtime=docker`

Comment: what is output of `ifconfig ens4` on worker nodes?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the routes like this:

```
Worker-0:
$ sudo route add -net 10.200.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 10.240.0.21
$ sudo route add -net 10.200.2.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 10.240.0.22

Worker-1:
$ sudo route add -net 10.200.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 10.240.0.20
$ sudo route add -net 10.200.2.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 10.240.0.22

Worker-2:
$ sudo route add -net 10.200.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 10.240.0.20
$ sudo route add -net 10.200.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 10.240.0.21
```

Comment: The result is SIOCADDRT: Network is unreachable. But i can ping to other node using the LAN IP

Comment: @NickyPuff can you share the output of `ifconfig` on all the worker nodes and try this on worker-0 `sudo route add -net 10.200.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 10.240.0.21`

Comment: Here is my ifconfig https://i.ibb.co/GFCL1tV/docker1.png and when i run the route command the result is SIOCADDRT https://i.ibb.co/DGM9GmC/docker2.png
I am using Docker https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/ not containderd

Comment: Wondering why netmask of `ens4` is `255.255.255.255`

Comment: :) that's how GCP works maybe ? All instances are hosted in GCP. I can't do anything about it

Comment: Can you see a similar output for this command `gcloud compute routes list --filter "network: kubernetes-the-hard-way"` as mentioned in the reference link

Comment: https://i.ibb.co/6PS9B3d/routes.png I have added routes also... i've been stuck on this link https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-the-hard-way/blob/master/docs/11-pod-network-routes.md for 2 days. In that link, we should can ping pod from other nodes even in the same node. But, i can not.

Comment: I don't know if i have to change my container runtime to remote (containerd). It's docker now.

Comment: Still stuck :(
I am using runc & containerd as kelsey made before... it's running. but i expect i can use docker like in GKE... so, i am creating new baremetal cluster same with GKE feature

Comment: @NickyPuff have you tried to add routes in Compute engine instead of GCP instances?

Comment: @OhHiMark yes i have already add Routes. But nvm, it's solved by using Calico. I am still asking in my mind, why basic CNI doesnt resolve it